# Consuming WCF service on Android using ksoap2 - Internal Server Error

Tags: android, .net, wcf, soap, ksoap2

I'm developing an Android client for a WCF service. There is a windows app that works with the service without any issues. However when I try to consume the service on Android, using kSoap2 - I get the 500 Internal Server Error. Obviously I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Here is my Java code:

```
// SOAP consts
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "/SignService";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ISignService/";
...
String url;
String method_name = "GetExistedSignData";

url = mServerAddress + SERVICE_NAME;

/* the connect logic goes here */
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method_name);

    request.addProperty("displayId", "HWI_00:1E:8C:87:7F:8D");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    androidHttpTransport.call(method_name, envelope);
    sb.append(envelope.toString() + "\n");
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

    //to get the data
    String resultData = result.toString();
    sb.append(resultData + "\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
    sb.append("IO Problem:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    sb.append("Parser Problem:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    sb.append("Error:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
}
```

Here is the HTTP dump of the windows client successfully invoking a method:

```
POST /SignService HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: ariadnetest.ariadne.vn
Content-Length: 995
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:r="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <r:Sequence s:mustUnderstand="1">
    <r:Identifier>urn:uuid:b6073cc9-d142-4045-90cb-1ae8d839d400</r:Identifier>
    <r:MessageNumber>1</r:MessageNumber>
    </r:Sequence>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/ISignService/GetExistedSignData</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:ad89a2da-6205-460b-b50c-9b354d83594d</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="9c91571d-e363-45da-ab5b-a83d48f3ec82">468b8556-f549-4d1f-969a-591aae05d4af</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
    <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://ariadnetest.ariadne.vn/SignService</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <GetExistedSignData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <displayId>HWI_00:1E:8C:87:7F:8D</displayId>
    </GetExistedSignData>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is the HTTP dump of my unsuccessful calling the same method:

```
POST /SignService HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: ksoap2-android/2.6.0+
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 358
Host: ariadnetest.ariadne.vn
Accept-Encoding: gzip

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <GetExistedSignData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <displayId>HWI_00:1E:8C:87:7F:8D</displayId>
    </GetExistedSignData>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

In return I get:

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 15:46:07 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2114
Connection: close
```

The most useful part of the error description says:

```
Error Code 64: Host not available
Background: The connection to the  Web server was lost.
```

I'm not very familiar with WCF and .NET so I'm out of options about what can be wrong. I did not develop the WCF service I need to consume in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have choice, it is best to not use SOAP on Android. SOAP is way more complex than REST and requires a sophisticated framework which is not available for Android, at least for now.

Comment: What are the other choices?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(method_name, envelope);
```

The first argument should be: NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. According to the kSoap2 docs the first argument is used to set the "soapAction" header field, which is not used in SOAP 1.2